# yii 2 params not binded properly in updateAll function

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i'm having problems when using the function `ActiveRecord::updateAll()`. Here is the code i use :

```
Branch::updateAll(
    [
        'parent' => ':p',
        'order' => ':o'
    ], [
        'id' => ':i'
    ], [
        ':p' => $line['parent'],
        ':o' => $line['order'],
        ':i' => $line['id'],
    ]);
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `branch` SET `parent`=':p', `order`=0 WHERE `id`=':i''
```

I can't find what i'm doing wrong... 
I tried changing names for the binded parameters and i also tried with 'anonymous' parameters (using `?` instead of `:p`) without success

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct version:

```
Branch::updateAll(
    [
        'parent' => $line['parent'],
        'order' => $line['order'],
    ],
    ['id' => $line['id']],
);
```

Alternative:

```
Branch::updateAll(
    [
        'parent' => $line['parent'],
        'order' => $line['order'],
    ],
    'id = :id',
    [':id' => $line['id']],
);
```

Comment: are the parameters protected against SQL injections using this method ?